# Neo4j GC overhead limit exceeded error while starting the Neo4j server

Tags: neo4j, garbage-collection, cypher

Hi I am receiving the following error while starting the neo4j server. How can I resolve this issue? I am unable to start the server also

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you've stopped the previous instance of neo4j you were running? If not, stop that and try again. If that doesn't fix the problem, try restarting the pc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

Comment: Please paste the error message here instead of posting an image.

Comment: @JpReddy yes i had stopped the previous instance and restarted my PC then also i' am facing the same problem... while starting neo4j it is occupying 100% of CPU and finally not responding

Comment: @the4kman  "Starting Neo4j failed: Component    org.neo4j.server.database.lifecyclemanagingDatabase@7ad02f70" was successfully intialized but failed to start Please see the attached cause "GC overhead limit exceeded" this is the error

Comment: Please help me to resolve this issue..